# How to set Emacs `bindat-pack` data

Tags: emacs

It seems i cant get `bindat-pack` to work correctly. Its a function to pack data into binary form:
https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Bindat-Examples.html

I have following sample code:

```
(require 'bindat)

(setq data-spec
   '((type      u8)
     (id        strz 8)))

(setq data (bindat-pack
            data-spec
            `((:type . 2)
              (:id . "Test"))))
```

`data` should now be packed correctly like described `data-spec`, but its just an empty string filled with zeros (`\x00`).

Does some have a clue what i'm doing wrong here?

I'm using Emacs 25.1.1 (x86_64-w64-mingw32) on windows 10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok i found a solution myself. The colon's are not needed when you set the data. The example code on the emacs page seems to be wrong, still not sure why.

Working code:

```
(require 'bindat)

(setq data-spec
   '((type      u8)
     (id        strz 8)))

(setq data (bindat-pack
        data-spec
        `((type . 2)
          (id . "Test"))))
```